# Trouble getting "left" value from parent div having display: flex

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I was trying to make a background slide animation when a button was clicked, but I cant seem to get exact value of "left" from the below code, obviously I am doing something wrong here...

I have tried to make ".btn" position: static/relative, both resulting in either "left"= "auto" or "0".

Tried offset(), position(), doesnt work for me. Any help will be much appreciated!

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var pos_left = $(this).css("left");
    $(".result").html(pos_left);
    //$(".animation").css("left", pos_left); (THIS IS EXPECTED)
    $(".animation").css("left", 35);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: min-content;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border: 2px black solid;
}
.btn {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: green;
    max-width: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 2px green solid;
    border-color: yellowgreen;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.animation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 34px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn">Box 1</div>
        <div class="btn">Box 2</div>
        <div class="btn">Boxie 3</div>
        <div class="btn">Boxie box 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="animation"></div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: I can't see where the left style of .tn will have been set up initially. I think it's only going to return to you what is in the CSS style, (which could be auto or 0 as you have found). What dimension are you wanting - the position of a .btn inside its parent div or....?

Comment: You'll probably need to get the computed style. Flex items don't tend to have a defined "left" rule. --- `getComputedStyle(this)`? Or did you mean `this.offsetLeft`?

Comment: wait does the value you set for `left` need to be in pixels? `35px`

Comment: There are quite a few units you can use to set e.g. left. CSS px is one of them. [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length has a useful list including %, em, vw....

Comment: @AHaworth 1) I dont think thta is the case, answer posted by Novy also does not include the "left" style in css. 2) Yeah i wanted to know the position of the div inside of its parent div.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was talking about this $(selector).offset(). I need to check getComputedStyle(), thanks for helping me.

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy No, it doesnt need to be as long as I have correct values in any units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply try to get your code work as naively as possible like this:

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var position = $(this).position();
    var pos_left = position.left;
    var elementWith = $(this).outerWidth();
    $(".result").html(pos_left);
    $(".animation").css("left", pos_left);
    $(".animation").width(elementWith)
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: min-content;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border: 2px black solid;
}
.btn {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: green;
    max-width: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 2px green solid;
    border-color: yellowgreen;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.animation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 34px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="btn">Box 1</div>
        <div class="btn">Box 2</div>
        <div class="btn">Boxie 3</div>
        <div class="btn">Boxie box 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="animation"></div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: uhhh huh, I am preety sure, I have tried the exact same thing before posting this post, the only thing different here is that, in my project I have used <button> instead of <div>. aybe that was the issue?, Or I should have skrewed something up. But Thank you for your answer, this is exactly the result what I wanted :)

Comment: @Sniper1999 may be something else was wrong. Because I had the same result with  button tags in the container. Ok to be honest  it was not exactly the same result because i had to add an init phase  on document ready for example. That means get the first button size for styling the animation to make it fit the first button size. By the way if the result fit your need may be you could accept it and up vote if you do not mind. It is part on civic duty on the community rules if I am not wrong.

Comment: I had insufficient reputation points as I had just created this account, anyways I did mark your answer as correct and upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

For the general case finding the position of an element can be done with the `getBoundingClientRect` function on the element.

The function returns an object from which you can get these properties: left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, height

x and y give position relative to the viewport which may be what you require.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my question, I wanted to get the position of the inner div, with respect to parent div, getBoundingClientRect seems to get viewport of the whole window and gives the position of the div with respect to the window rather than parent div, I think this could work, but i would need to bring the ".animation"div outside all the parent divs and give it dimentions of the viewport. This is a good workaround, but I think @Novy found a cleaner solution. Thanks for your answer :)